# PHP MYSQL Cant get user data to pull from database, only id and name

Tags: php, mysql, database

I cant seem to get any of my users other information pulled from the database other than their username and ID and im not understanding why, heres my code trying to call it from session.

```
// Now we check if the data was submitted, isset will check if the data exists.
if ( !isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) ) {
    // Could not get the data that should have been sent.
    die ('Username and/or password does not exist!');
}
// Prepare our SQL
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM accounts WHERE username = ?')) {
    // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), hash the password using the PHP password_hash function.
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $password);
        $stmt->fetch();
        // Account exists, now we verify the password.
        if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
            // Verification success! User has loggedin!
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            $_SESSION['title'] = $title;
            $_SESSION['website'] = $website;
            $_SESSION['youtube'] = $youtube;
            $_SESSION['facebook'] = $facebook;
            $_SESSION['paypalemail'] = $paypalemail;
            echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['username'] . '!';
                echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['title'] . '!';
      echo'<a href="/profile.php">My Profile </a>';
        } else {
            echo 'Incorrect username and/or password!';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Incorrect username and/or password!';
    }
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    echo 'Could not prepare statement!';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are the variables `$title`,`$website`,`$youtube`,`$facebook`,`$paypalemail` coming from? If they are stored in the `accounts` table with the same column names as the variable names you used you need to retrieve them along with the id and password.

Change

```
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM accounts WHERE username = ?')) {
```

to

```
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT 
    `id`,
    `password`,
    `title`,
    `website`,
    `youtube`,
    `facebook`,
    `paypalemail` 
FROM accounts WHERE username = ?')) {
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes they are in the databse and I attempted to add them their to no prevail but this looks exactly what I was wanting thank you sir!